# Dynamically creating a row in a table on button click and displaying it on modification of page

Tags: javascript

I have created a dynamic row in a table on button click, I have inserted some values in the row and I have saved the data on the page by clicking on save button.

the data is getting saved properly, however when I am modifying the same page all the data is getting displayed except the dynamic row that I have created previously.

I want to know how should I display that new dynamic row with the data that I have inserted in it in the modification of that page...

Comment: Why is your question **bold**-ed?

Comment: because its a *puts on glasses*  bold question

Comment: @OP when you say "the data is getting saved properly", what do you mean by "saved" ? saved where? because you know, unless you save the data in a file on the computer, its not really being "saved" anywhere and will disappear as soon as you reload the page

Comment: By save I mean the data is getting saved in the oracle database properly.All the data including the data I inserted in the dynamic row... is getting saved in the database, but when I am trying to modify the same page....firstly I am not getting how should I display that dynamic row that I created on button click.... on modification of the same page .

Comment: I have a link for modifying the same page, in which all the data which I saved earlier is getting displayed.But I have a problem in displaying that dynamic row and its data on modification..I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You tagged this as JavaScript only, but i think you use a backend language, maybe php, yes? And what do you mean by "i have a link for modifying the page"? Please be more specific, the link, what does it do? And besides, you keep saying "on modification of page" what is that supposed to mean? What else beaides JavaScript are you using?